# How do i manualy set the $id of the current $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If would like to set the id of a scope, so i can reuse it for different purposes. Can i set the $id of an angular-directive during the compile process?

Comment: You can't, if you read the documentation, they calculate it using their in built function. And for future reference you can't do anything with the creation of scopes. I read the entire thing, and there is no way to tap into that creation process. [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), [GitHub Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L86), Ctrl+F then search `$new`

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea which will mess up angular's inner work. Can't you just add your own id property to the scope?

Comment: In fact the only way I know, and can suggest, is to write your own route provider, because then you control the scope that is passed to the controller, but that is effort. You want to create a service(factory) or provider.

Comment: `Controller as` may be the closest you get to naming the scopes